# jQuery.post() not going through?

Tags: jquery

On button click I have the simple [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("/cgi-bin/stats.exe");
});
```

However, nothing seems to go through to the server side. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attaching it to the document ready event. Instead, you should attach is to your button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myButtonId').click(function(){
           $.post("/cgi-bin/stats.exe");
     });
});
```